# Replacing string1 with string 2 in lines containing string3 - with string1 occuring multiple times

Tags: text-processing, sed

I use the following command to replace a specific string (replace string1 with string2) in lines containing another string (string3).

```
  sed -i '/string3/ s/string1/string2/' file.txt
```

PROBLEM...

The command above works fine - BUT - it only replaces string1 with string2 on the first occurrance of string1 in the line containing string3.

I have to run the command multiple times to make sure all occurrances of string1 are replaced.

```
  sed -i '/string3/ s/string1/string2/' file.txt
  sed -i '/string3/ s/string1/string2/' file.txt
  sed -i '/string3/ s/string1/string2/' file.txt
```

Is there a way to replace all occurances of string1 in a line containing string3 in a single step?

That could help me shrink my bash file.

Big thanks.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is to add sed's "global replacement" flag to the end:

```
sed -i '/string3/ s/string1/string2/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks - That simple? - I was wondering why the g wasn't there in the posts I was reading.  Go figure. Again, thanks.

Comment: Depends entirely on what you want to have happen! Glad it helped; don't forget the checkmark if it did solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, while the obvious solution in this case is to add the `g` flag, there are some cases where you may want to run the `s/string1/string2/` (or `s/string1/string2/g`) command several times.

For instance if instead of `string2`, you have `str`, on an input like:

```
string1ing1
```

`s/string1/str/g` would result to:

```
string1
```

If you wanted `str` instead, you'd need another `s/string1/str/g`. With `sed`, there's an idiomatic way to run a substitution as long as it succeeds using the `t` command:

```
sed '
  /string3/{
    :1
    s/string1/string2/
    t1
  }'
```

`t` branches to the `:1` label only if there has been a successful `s` command.

Answer (score 0):

while question is  tagged with `sed` and given perfect answer above, but here is awk version for those will looking it.

```
awk '/string3/{gsub("string1", "string2", $0)}1' infile.txt
```